# An analytic number theoretic average

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am interested in knowing the exact asymptotic formula (if it exists) of

$\displaystyle \sum_{n \leq X} \mu^2(n) 2^{-\omega(n)},$

where $\omega(n)$ denotes the number of distinct prime divisors of $n$. I've looked all over and it does not seem to be written down.

Since we are restricting to square-free numbers, this is equal to the sum

$\displaystyle \sum_{n \leq X} \frac{\mu^2(n)}{d(n)},$

where $d(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$.

Comment: As far as I know, the key trick that makes this problem tractable with the positive exponent, namely $2^{\omega(n)} = \sum_{d | n} \mu^2(d)$, is not available here... which makes this problem more involved.

Comment: $F(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)^2}{2^{\omega(n)}}n^{-s} = \prod_p (1+\frac{p^{-s}}{2})$ thus (looking at the logarithms) $G(s) = \frac{1}{\zeta(s)^{1/2}}F(s)$ is analytic for $\Re(s)> 1/2$ and $F(s) =G(1)  (s-1)^{-1/2}+\mathcal{O}(1+|\log s|)$ on $\Re(s) \ge 1-\epsilon$. Applying the same method as for the prime number theorem you'll get $\sum_{n \le x} \frac{\mu(n)^2}{2^{\omega(n)}} =\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty} \frac{F(s)}{s} x^{s} ds\sim  \frac{G(1)}{2i\pi}\int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty} \frac{(s-1)^{-1/2}}{s} x^{s} ds $